# Why doesn't this struct assignment work in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    struct point
    {
        int x, y;
    };

    struct rectangle
    {
           struct point upper_left, lower_right;
    };

    struct rectangle *p = malloc(sizeof(struct rectangle));

    p->upper_left = {10,25};

    return 0;
}
```

This gives:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
   19 |     p->upper_left = {10,25};
```

Comment: If you're limited to C89 (C90) you can do it with `p->upper_left.x = 10; p->upper_left.y = 25;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax `{ ... }` is an *initializer list*, and may only appear as part of an initialization, not an assignment.

What you *can* do however is use a compound literal (which includes an initializer) to create a struct object on the fly and use that for the assignment.

```
 p->upper_left = (struct point){10,25};
```

Comment: @programmerc3981143 Specified the wrong type.  The edit should fix it.

Comment: @programmerc3981143 "does not work" is never a useful or sufficient description of the problem you face.